# Writing a method that I can call in a separate script in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a method that I can call in a different script, however, I am not able to successfully call the script(s) with the way I have it written. This is one of the scripts I am trying to call (the second is very similar:

```
#!usr/bin/env python

import re
import urllib
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

date = datetime.now()
date1 = date + timedelta(days=1)
date2 = date + timedelta(days=2)


class city :
        def __init__(self, city_name, link) :
                self.name = city_name
                self.url = link
                self.wind1 = 0

    def retrieveTemps(self) :
            filehandle = urllib.urlopen(self.url)

            # get lines from result into array
            lines = filehandle.readlines()

            # (for each) loop through each line in lines
            line_number = 0 # a counter for line number
            for line in lines:
                    line_number = line_number + 1 # increment counter

                    # find string, position otherwise position is -1

                    position2 = line.rfind('<ul class="stats">')

                    #String is found in line

                    if position2 > 0 :
                            self.wind0 = lines[line_number + 1].split('</strong>')[0].split('style="">')[-1]

                            break # done with loop, break out of it

            return ('c.wind0')

            filehandle.close()

m1 = city('Mexico City', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/mexico-city/242560/daily-weather-forecast/242560?day=2')
m3 = city('Veracruz', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/veracruz/236233/daily-weather-forecast/236233?day=2')
m5 = city('Tampico', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/tampico/235985/daily-weather-forecast/235985?day=2')
m7 = city('Nuevo Laredo', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/nuevo-laredo/235983/daily-weather-forecast/235983?day=2')
m9 = city('Monterrey', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/monterrey/244681/daily-weather-forecast/244681?day=2')
m11 = city('S. Luis Potosi', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/san-luis-potosi/245369/daily-weather-forecast/245369?day=2')
m13 = city('Queretaro', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/queretaro/245027/daily-weather-forecast/245027?day=2')
m15 = city('Laz. Cardenas', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/lazaro-cardenas/239054/daily-weather-forecast/239054?day=2')

cities = []
cities.append(m1)
cities.append(m3)
cities.append(m5)
cities.append(m7)
cities.append(m9)
cities.append(m11)
cities.append(m13)
cities.append(m15)
```

I try to call this script and another script with this:

```
#!usr/bin/env python

from script import getCities
from script2 import getWind

cities = getCities()
wind = getWind()

for c in wind :
        c.retrieveTemps()
for c in cities :
        c.retrieveTemps()

print(c.name,c.high0,c.low0,c.high1,c.low1,c.weather0,c.weather1,c.wind0,c.wind1)
```

c.wind0 is found with script2, while all the other variables are found with script1. If I import script1 second, I get the error: AttributeError: city instance has no attribute 'wind1', which has no attribute with script2, it is associated with script1. It seems to be ignoring the first script I import.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE:

Using your suggestions, plus something else, I came up with this and it works perfectly.

```
#!usr/bin/env python

import script1
import script2

wind = script2.getWind()
cities = script.getCities()

for c in cities :
        c.retrieveTemps()
for w in wind :
        w.retrieveWind()

# iterate over both lists in parallel, zip returns a tuple 
for c, w in zip(cities, wind) :
    print(c.name,c.high0,c.low0,c.high1,c.low1,c.weather0,c.weather1,c.wind0,w.wind1)
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: You're importing `city`, but not `cities`.

Comment: Alright, I changed the script to import both city and cities, but I am having another problem that I restated in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make everything below the class a function that returns `cities`, import the function, and call it, setting `cities` to a new local variable. Then you can run your for loop.

Disclaimer: I didn't test this at all.

Step1:

```
def getCities():
    m1 = city('Mexico City', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/mexico-city/242560/daily-weather-forecast/242560?day=2')
    m3 = city('Veracruz', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/veracruz/236233/daily-weather-forecast/236233?day=2')
    m5 = city('Tampico', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/tampico/235985/daily-weather-forecast/235985?day=2')
    m7 = city('Nuevo Laredo', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/nuevo-laredo/235983/daily-weather-forecast/235983?day=2')
    m9 = city('Monterrey', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/monterrey/244681/daily-weather-forecast/244681?day=2')
    m11 = city('S. Luis Potosi', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/san-luis-potosi/245369/daily-weather-forecast/245369?day=2')
    m13 = city('Queretaro', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/queretaro/245027/daily-weather-forecast/245027?day=2')
    m15 = city('Laz. Cardenas', 'http://www.accuweather.com/en/mx/lazaro-cardenas/239054/daily-weather-forecast/239054?day=2')


    cities = []
    cities.append(m1)
    cities.append(m3)
    cities.append(m5)
    cities.append(m7)
    cities.append(m9)
    cities.append(m11)
    cities.append(m13)
    cities.append(m15)

    return cities
```

Step 2:

```
from script1 import getCities
```

Step 3:

```
cities = getCities()

for c in cities :
    c.retrieveTemps()
    print(c.name,c.high0,c.low0,c.high1,c.low1,c.weather0,c.weather1,c.wind0,c.wind1)
```

Comment: Sorry. I am new at python and not exactly sure how I would do this.

Comment: When I do that it gives me the follow error for the line "cities = script1.getCities()"...'NameError: name 'script1' is not defined'

Comment: Oh, I guess get rid of script1 and just use getCities(). Yeah, I don't use Python much...

Comment: ok. That fixed that. However, I am still having the same error I had in part 2 of my original post. I am calling it with the code I added in to the original post:

Comment: Okay, so first of all, retrieveTemps() is returning the string 'c.wind0'. I assume you want it to actually return the value of self.wind0 or a list or something. Then, when you loop through the cities, you need to set a variable to c.retrieveTemps() or else the output of the function goes nowhere. You'll probably want to be appending to a list the values of c.retrieveTemps() as you loop. Then you can use the values from that list in your print statement.

Answer (score 1):

In your main script you use the variable `c` to reference a "wind" and then "cities". It the end of the loops the variable `c` will now reference the last city from the cities list.  Therefore it won't have any "wind" attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, i would copy and paste the method from the first file to the file you're using right now, because as far as i know, there isn't a way to call a method from a different script, not sure,maybe there is, but the easiest thing for me would be to copy and paste the method. hope i helped... :)

Comment: A fundamental ability of all good programming languages is the ability to call external methods. This is what `import` is all about: including external methods into memory to help execution of a script. Every coding language is in fact no more than an engine that understands its own language and a series of external methods written by the author of that language that breaks advanced functions (like Python's `lower()`, which turns all letters in a string to lower case) into smaller functions, so that you don't have to code everything yourself all the time.

Comment: @JWarner112 ok, i understand, but i've only been programming python for about a month, so i thought that it's not possible, but apparently i've been proven wrong... i'll keep that in mind next time

Comment: It's no problem, my friend. We're all learning! I just started Python a month and a half ago myself, but I've dedicated a lot of time to it. Besides, this is an overarching concept of programming in general, and those can be even harder to grasp. Try the Codecademy Python tutorial [here](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python). It doesn't work perfectly, but you can write your code [here](http://labs.codecademy.com) and manipulate the URLs to get through it all :)

Comment: @JWarner112 i dedicated at least 3 hours a day, usually 5 or more, i've done about 44% of the python in codecademy, it's a good website, and at the moment i'm learning from a book called python programming for the absolute beginner, it's pretty good. i'd recommend getting it, it teaches python 3.1.1. also, i used codecademy ages ago to start learning java, but it was a few years back i didn't understand it, i might return to java later, my friend said he can teach me it

Comment: @JWarner112 the book it bigger than A5 but smaller than A4, 432 pages or so, and explained in detail, there's a second one in the series called more python programming for the absoluute beginner, and it introduces even more modules like pygame :)